# User id is not passing through in the URL in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm passing the user id in the URL but its taking '0'
`http://localhost:1400/api/Values/GetLeaves/0`

As it is suppose to show the list of id when I select the particular id it should show the leaves of the particular member but it just showing only '0'.

when I print the id which pass through it just showing '0'

This is what I have tried
views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def GetLeaves(request, userid):

    if request.method == 'GET':    
       print("GetLeavesBRG--->", userid)
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GPHGetUserLeaveDetailsBRG] @user=%s',(userid,))
       result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    
       print(result_set)
       response_data = []
       for row in result_set:
           response_data.append({              
               "FromDate":row[0]
           })

       return Response(response_data)
```

urls.py:

```
path('Values/GetLeaves/<int:userid>', GetLeaves, name='GetLeaves')
```

Comment: Can you show the url that is supposed to take you to this view.

Comment: I have mentioned it above... this s the path path('Values/GetLeaves/<int:userid>', GetLeaves, name='GetLeaves')

Comment: url path its working but its not taking the user id

Comment: I guess i misunderstood your question.   If you put `http://localhost:1400/api/Values/GetLeaves/0` in the browser then of course the `<int:userid>` part of your path will get that value, which *is* 0.  If you have a link in a template that you click to get to this path, then show that.  I don't understand what you mean by "I'm passing the user id in the URL but its taking '0' ".  Sorry.

Comment: Instead of showing the user id all it shows only  this 'http://localhost:1400/api/Values/GetLeaves/0'  I'm just implementing it to the frontend code. API is working is working properly as well